# I want to have certain flags for items in my Rails app, wondering if I should extend my Tag class or create a whole new Flag class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not the most advanced programmer, and when it comes to inheritance I know what it is but I probably don't use it when I should. So I'm asking for some opinions on the following:

I have a Rails app that tracks items that have various time based routines. i.e. a pair of protective boots might need to be inspected every 12 months, and also professionally cleaned at least once in a 12 month period. They have a lifetime of 10 years. Every day the app runs a cron job that updates a table with critical dates like:

```
|next_inspection_due|next_cleaning_due|retirement_due|
|    2019-05-28     |    2019-09-09   |  2025-02-01  |
```

If any of these are `< today` it will check to make sure a flag has been set in the Flaggings table. The flags would be something like 'Inspection Due'. If someone sends an item in for cleaning, the completion of the cleaning event would cause the `next_cleaning_due` date to be updated to one year from that date.

I also have the standard Tagging structure common in so many apps with a Tag model and a Tagging model with the associated tables...

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :items, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :item
end
```

My "flags" are just another form of tag conceptually. But they are defined in the app and limited to `[:inspection_due, :cleaning_due, :retirement_due]`. Is there any value in having my Flag and Flagging models inherit from Tag and Tagging respectively? Currently they just mirror them:

```
class Flag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :flaggings
  has_many :items, through: :flaggings
end

class Flagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :flag
  belongs_to :item
end
```

with the associated tables. Am I duplicating too much? Not sure if it would gain me anything by having

```
class Flag < Tag
```

Or should I just make those three flags "predefined tags" that are only set or unset by the app when it runs its status checks and can't be used by the end user in the normal tagging space?

Hope this isn't too broad or vague. Just writing this out makes me think I'm duplicating code needlessly.

Comment: Another option is [polymorphic associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Comment: Aside from the relationships that looks really similar (It's a really common pattern), is Flag a special kind of Tag or you just feel you could reuse the Tag model for your Flags? I mean, think about the semantic, the uses of each of them. Does it makes sense that a Flag inherits all the behaviour of the Tag class? It's really hard to answer this questions (these are even explicitly forbiden by SO guidelines as too opinion based, it may get closed).